# Terraform nested objects transformation

Tags: terraform

I'm working on a module and I have a variable structure like the following:

```
input = [
   {
      "prod_db" : {...someOtherAttributes}
      "prod_app": {...someOtherAttributes}
   },
   {
      "stage_db" : {...someOtherAttributes}
      "stage_app": {...someOtherAttributes}
   },
   {
      "dev_db" : {...someOtherAttributes}
      "dev_app": {...someOtherAttributes}
   }
]
```

is there a way to have a map of only the second-level object? something like this:

```
result = {
   "prod_db" : {...someOtherAttributes},
   "prod_app": {...someOtherAttributes},
   "stage_db" : {...someOtherAttributes},
   "stage_app": {...someOtherAttributes},
   "dev_db" : {...someOtherAttributes},
   "dev_app": {...someOtherAttributes}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected `result` is invalid data structure. I guess that you actually want the following:

```
    result = merge(var.input...)
```

Where `...` is for [Expanding Function Arguments](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/function-calls.html#expanding-function-arguments).

Comment: yes you're right, I have fixed my post accordingly, I'll try your approach right now.
thank youuu

Comment: it worked like a charm, I guess that's what I was missing, the fact that I had an invalid structure in my head :/ . Thank you so much.

Comment: @SabrineMihni No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: The doc needs to be updated to give the `...` operator in HCL2 a name to more easily remember its functionality and refer to it. Similar operators in Ruby, Python, and JS all have names.

Comment: @MattSchuchard In python it would be `splat` operator. Is it called the same in Ruby or JS?

Comment: @Marcin Yes also called splat in Ruby, but spread in JS. In Golang (assuming derived from that) just referred to as an ellipsis in a variadic function. I keep forgetting what this operator does because it has no name.